# Facebook gem for Rails app

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, ruby-on-rails-4, ruby-on-rails-3.2, rubygems

Is there any ruby gem which can be used to see Facebook post in rails app, also allows to post through rails app. I tried this gem http://www.sitepoint.com/ruby-social-gems-facebook/ but it is not showing facebook page post.

Comment: can you be more specific? Are you asking for the correct permissions?

Comment: I want to use it for facebook page not for facebook profile.Is it possible to fetch fb post directly into my rails app with the help of this gem

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`koala` seems to be popular choice for the task you specified.

> Koala is a Facebook library for Ruby, supporting the Graph API (including the batch requests and photo uploads), the REST API, realtime updates, test users, and OAuth validation.

https://github.com/arsduo/koala

Documentation is here:

https://github.com/arsduo/koala/wiki/Graph-API

Comment: I want to use it for facebook page not for facebook profile.Is it possible  to fetch fb post directly into my rails app with the help of this gem

Comment: I got it  thanx @dimakura